# What is the proper way to turn off wiped Windows 8 computer?

Tags: windows, windows-8, shutdown

I just reset the computer to factory settings and wiped out all the contents of HDDs.

It automatically restarted and opened "Region and language" screen.

What is the proper way to shut it down at this point?

I know it sounds as a dumb question, but there are no other buttons on the screen.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I do know I can turn off the computer by holding the Power button, but I'm not 100% sure that this is the intended way to do so.
I need to return the PC and it should be in the same condition as when it was bought.

Comment: Is that a *proper* way to do it? I don't want to be choosing "Start windows normally" afterwards. I need to return the computer to the service and it should be in the same condition as when I took it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Push the power button on your chassis like usual (don't hold it), if ACPI is initialized it should fire off the regular shut down sequence.

If it's not it'll just shut right off, which would be fine in this case since it's not doing anything that requires a proper OS shutdown (no background services, etc. running that need to be stopped).